# Reading the data which is in a map[string]interface{}

Tags: json, parsing, go, interface, marshalling

Source server return the data in a Json format of multiple object 
    interfaces, how can we parse such data ?

I am using a variable of JSON map[string]interface{}  type to hold the result from server

```
 The data return from Server.
"data": [
       {
        "group": "PAA_TEST",
        "id": "2018-04-10T09:24:18.000000Z",
        "name": "PAA_STATION",
        "released": true,
        "version": 33
    },
    {
        "group": "PAA_TEST",
        "id": "2018-03-19T10:50:21.000000Z",
        "name": "PAA_STATION",
        "released": false,
        "version": 32
    }
```

my fmt.print output outputdata["data"] //where output data is of JSON 
                                            map[string]interface{}

```
    [
       map[group:PAA_TEST id:2018-04-10T09:24:18.000000Z name:PAA_STATION 
       released:true version:33] 
       map[group:PAA_TEST id:2018-03-19T10:50:21.000000Z name:PAA_STATION 
       released:false version:32] 
   ]
```

How can we iterate with multiple Map interfaces? For example, if I just want to process the information with released status as true. I am trying various method for indexing but no luck yet.

Comment: Let's step up a level. Is there a reason that you you are using `map[string]interface{}` instead of a type that matches the structure of the data more directly.  For example `struct { Data []struct{ Group, ID, Name string; Released bool; Version int }}`.

Comment: Yes, it is a reusable and common function which interacts with the server and its return type is map[string]interface{}.

Comment: In most cases, common functions like that can be written to work with a type specific to the response.  Share that function if you'd like assistance with that.

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new to go, I am not sure if I understood you correctly. I can create an extra function to transform the data to a desired struct format, but I am not sure how to parse or iterate over the existing data format. Would you suggest a for loop of similar kind - [link](https://play.golang.org/p/9OEPzbf0Me0) for the transformation?

Comment: I am suggesting that you let the JSON decoder to the heavy lifting by modifying the common function that interacts with the server to work with arbitrary types.  Is the structure of the JSON response known in advance for each API on the server?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately the response structure are varied and are not known in advance.

Comment: I know the fields for the API on which I am working not each and every API which can be called, but the core/common function is general it just hits the server and gives the response, irrespective of any logic. It is simple http request and response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to decode the JSON directly to a Go type that matches the structure of the data.  This avoids the type assertions required to dig through a `map[string]interface{}`.

I'll assume that the common function looks something like this:

```
func request(path string, ... more arguments) (map[string]interface{}}, error) {
      ...
      resp, err := client.Do(req)
      if err != nil {
         return nil, err
      }
      defer resp.Body.Close()
      ...
      var result map[string]interface{}
      err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result)
      return result, err
}
```

Change the function to take a pointer to the result as an argument:

```
func request(pv interface{}, path string, ... more arguments) error {
      ...
      resp, err := client.Do(req)
      if err != nil {
         return err
      }
      defer resp.Body.Close()
      ...
      err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(pv)
      return err
}
```

Call this modified function like this:

```
var result struct { 
    Data []struct{ 
        Group, ID, Name string
        Released bool
        Version int 
    }
}
err := request(&result, "some/path", ... more arguments )
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

for _, d := range result.Data {
   if !d.Released {
       continue
   }
   fmt.Println(d.Group, d.ID, d.Name, d.Version)
   ... process d
}
```

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64201687/3317808