# How to read unicode characters from data source

Tags: go

Below code is able to read data source(following all reading rules), having text(with UTF-8 encodings of size one byte):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

type MyStringData struct {
    str       string
    readIndex int
}

func (myStringData *MyStringData) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {

    // convert `str` string to slice of bytes
    strBytes := []byte(myStringData.str)

    // if `readIndex` is GTE source length, return `EOF` error
    if myStringData.readIndex >= len(strBytes) {
        return 0, io.EOF // `0` bytes read
    }

    // get next readable limit (exclusive)
    nextReadLimit := myStringData.readIndex + len(p)

    if nextReadLimit >= len(strBytes) {
        nextReadLimit = len(strBytes)
        err = io.EOF
    }

    // get next bytes to copy and set `n` to its length
    nextBytes := strBytes[myStringData.readIndex:nextReadLimit]
    n = len(nextBytes)

    // copy all bytes of `nextBytes` into `p` slice
    copy(p, nextBytes)

    // increment `readIndex` to `nextReadLimit`
    myStringData.readIndex = nextReadLimit

    // return values
    return
}

func main() {

    // create data source
    src := MyStringData{str: "Hello Amazing World!"} // 学中文

    p := make([]byte, 3) // slice of length `3`

    // read `src` until an error is returned
    for {
        // read `p` bytes from `src`
        n, err := src.Read(p)
        fmt.Printf("%d bytes read, data:%s\n", n, p[:n])

        // handle error
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("--end-of-file--")
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Oops! some error occured!", err)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
$
$
$ go run src/../Main.go
3 bytes read, data:Hel
3 bytes read, data:lo 
3 bytes read, data:Ama
3 bytes read, data:zin
3 bytes read, data:g W
3 bytes read, data:orl
2 bytes read, data:d!
--end-of-file--
$
$
```

---

But the above code is unable to read data source having text(with UTF-8 encodings of size greater than one byte) as shown below:

```
  src := MyStringData{str: "Hello Amazing World!学中文"}
```

Below is the output:

```
$
$
$ go run src/../Main.go
3 bytes read, data:Hel
3 bytes read, data:lo 
3 bytes read, data:Ama
3 bytes read, data:zin
3 bytes read, data:g W
3 bytes read, data:orl
3 bytes read, data:d!�
3 bytes read, data:���
3 bytes read, data:���
2 bytes read, data:��
--end-of-file--
$
$
```

---

**Edit:**

With the comments given on usage of `strings.NewReader()`, below is the code modified:

```
// create data source
src := strings.NewReader("Hello Amazing World!学中文") // 学中文

// p := make([]byte, 3) // slice of length `3`

// read `src` until an error is returned
for {
    // read `p` bytes from `src`
    ch, n, err := src.ReadRune()
    // n, err := src.Read(p)
    fmt.Printf("%d bytes read, data:%c\n", n, ch)

    // handle error
    if err == io.EOF {
        fmt.Println("--end-of-file--")
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Oops! some error occured!", err)
        break
    }
}
```

---

How to read unicode characters without splitting a character(say `学`) in two `Read` calls?

Comment: What is wrong with the standard `strings.Reader`?

Comment: In general, you cannot prevent read from returning part of a code point.  Th

Comment: @MuffinTop cannot prevent read from returning part of a code point.... Isn't this a bad abstraction?

Comment: `io.Reader` is not an abstraction for decoding unicode, it's an abstraction for reading data, which obviously isn't always utf8 encoded.

Comment: @JimB how to use `strings.Reader` to resolve this problem?

Comment: @overexchange: resolve _what_ problem? You're expecting an `io.Reader` to do something it doesn't inherently do. You can use `strings.Reader` to turn a `string` into a simple `io.Reader` and use it accordingly, or you can use suggestions like those in the answer below to ensure you handle complete runes.

Answer (score 3):

Use something from [bufio](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/), e.g. a `bufio.Reader`'s `ReadRune` function, or a `bufio.Scanner` with a scan function that only returns one or more complete runes (using `DecodeRune` and `FullRune` from [unicode/utf8](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/) to validate, as the stdlib `bufio.ScanRunes` does).

You could do it yourself by buffering incomplete runes in a slice and appending to it with successive reads, but that would just be duplicating what `Scanner` does.